# Dictionary to flattened vector and then vector back to dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, vector

I need to flatten a dictionary of weights and biases to do gradient checking with it, I have created this function to flatten my dictionary, which works but I can't seem to find a way to revert the process.

```
@staticmethod
def flatten_dic(dic):
    keys = []
    count = 0
    theta = np.array([])
    for i in dic.keys():
        new_vector = np.reshape(dic[i], (-1, 1))
        keys = keys + [i] * new_vector.shape[0]
        if count == 0:
            theta = new_vector
        else:
            theta = np.concatenate((theta, new_vector), axis=0)
        count = count + 1
    return theta, keys
```

With an input of

```
{"W1":[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]],"W2":[1,2,3]}
```

It outputs

```
[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = {"W1":[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]],"W2":[1,2,3]}

result = []

def flatten(_list): 
    if type(_list[0]) == list: 
        for e in _list: 
           flatten(e) 
    else: 
       result.extend(_list) 

[flatten(e) for e in r.values()]
```

This will give you a flatten list in result, This will also preserve your original dictionary.

Comment: But my problem is how do I revert the process, because i want to change the data inside the flattened vector and transform it back into a dictionary

Comment: Suppose somebody gives you a flattened list and tell you to construct a dictionary from it, can you do it?
Make a deep copy of your dictionary and do whatever you want with it. If you can preserve your original duct, What's the need to reconstructing it?

Comment: yes but I need to reconstruct it to a dictionary in my case for use in forward propagation, it wouldn't be possible to build a dictionary from just the flattened list, but I can also extract the keys, so with a combination of keys and the flattened list I believe it to be possible